# Multiple Crystal Report to be printed on same report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that takes only about 1/3rd of the report space.
I have field read from the database which is an integer value.
I wish to print this report number of times as read from the database on the same page.
Any idea on how this can be achieved?

I can only use crystal report for achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if the number is high then 3? Or is the number always 3 or less?

Comment: Did this question get answered? I am having the same issue and can't seem to find a proper answer anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

You can create another report and add your current report as a subreport multiple times

Comment: but that would print the report a static number of times.
I wish to print the report based on a value which is read from the Database.

Comment: my answer was too long and didn't fit as a comment. check the @NumberOfCopies parameter suggestion above

Answer (score 0):

Lan is correct, build another report and add your current report as a subreport.

Here's the trick:

1. On your main report, have it make a list of all of the items that
   you'd like to run the sub-report on.
2. On your sub-report, add a parameter called "itemNumber" or something like that. Then change your Subreport Links so the new "itemNumber" parameter is linked to the item on your top level report.
3. Now hide the field on the main report but leave the
   subreport visible.!

[image]

This should make your report run for all items at one time.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can create a table with the maximum number of prints you will ever use. For example if you think you might need to print the report 100 times your table should contain records from 1 to 100.  So lets assume this is the case- create a table , name it Copies and add a field CopyNo. Create a 100 records and set CopyNo from 1 to 100.  Create the a main report based on Copies table - the record selection formula will be something like :
Copies.CopyNo<=@NumberOfCopies

@NumberOfCopies is a parameter , which you can set in order to control the printed copies. Create your actual report as a subreport and place it **in the details section** of the main report. When you run the report it will ask you for the number of copies and when you insert it, will print the same subreport as many times as the number you provide.